# how can I insert an image using Jsonservice in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

We are doing an app which uses `Jsonservice`(`restful` webservice) for back-end proccess and `Android` for front end.

This is what i need:

```
public string display(string name, string photo) {
  //need to convert the string "photo" varbinary;
  //display image in a gridview
}
```

I want to insert an image into database.my friend is doing the front end work. he will pass the image as string through json service.
I want to store this as a var binary and finally want to display the image in a `gridview`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format `photo` is in. If the format is Base64 you can use

```
byte[] photoData = Convert.FromBase64String(photo);
```

To convert the string into a byte array and store it in a varbinary field.

Comment: if the format is not Base64 ,then..suppose  it is a normal string then..how can I convert it  as varbinary so that I can store my image?

Comment: how can a photo be a normal string? text != image

Comment: So the text is in somekind of binary format. You just need to know what format it is

Comment: yes . you are right Mr.SynerCoder. but i got image in a string format. how can i insert and retrieve the image.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is on the RowCreated event, cast the row object as the correct object type, then generate the images and append them to the row. In the example below there is an Item Template in my grid view with a div entitled imageDiv.

```
<asp:TemplateField  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="My Image">
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="imageDiv" runat="server" style="display: none">
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


    protected void MyGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            MyObjectType someData = (MyObjectType)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (null != someData)
            {
                HtmlContainerControl imageDiv = (HtmlContainerControl)e.Row.FindControl("imageDiv");
                imageDiv.InnerHtml = "<img id=\"img1\" runat=\"server\" src=\"" + "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(someData.Pictures[0]) + "\" alt=\"Return\" width=\"180\" height=\"120\" style=\"padding:4px\" />";

            }

        }
    }
```

In this example however, someData.Pictures is a collection of byte Array. In your case if you already have the Base64String no conversion would be required.